# Archiving app with opensource libraries

Tags: ios, distribution, archive, xcode4.3

I got an app with SBJson opensource librarie.

[image]

When i run the project on a simulator it work perfect. And when i tried to archived my app this process break when archived a class with such lines:

```
#import <SBJson/SBJson.h>
```

Error:

[image]

Any ideas? Thnx

Comment: where is SBJson stored? When you include SBJson.h you have to give your class the relative path to that file.

Comment: you can see it on the first screenshot. when i run project on simulator it work perfect

Comment: maybe it is an issue of the header search path.